# upload files from remote VM without graphic interface to google drive

Tags: virtual-machine, remote, google-drive

I would like to upload a zipped folder to my google drive.  The file is large and takes a long time to download to my local machine and even longer to upload it to drive. I was hoping to save some time by sending it directly from the VM.  In Drive, I know you can either slide objects into the window or search for them on your local machine.  Does anyone have any idea how this would work from a remote VM? In my case, I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: What platform are you using?  Windows? Debian? CentOS? Ubuntu...?

Comment: I am using ubuntu... should have put that in the question, will fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"grive2" is a command line tool that can be used to do a sync between the local filesystem and google drive.  It's not automatic like some GUI tools, but it works pretty well.

There appear to be PPA's available for Ubuntu which may make it easier to work with: http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/grive2-grive-fork-with-google-drive.html

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, 4 years after google promised a Linux client for google drive, there is still none from them.  However, you can use [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive) or [gsync](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Rsync_with_Google_Drive).